converting .usdz to .obj results in flat rectangle - iOS Model I/O sdk
I'm using the Apple RoomPlan sdk to generate a .usdz file, which works fine, and gives me a 3D scan of my room.
But when I try to use MDLAsset to convert that output into an .obj file, it comes out as a completely flat model shaped like a rectangle. Here is my Swift code:
let destinationFolderURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appending(path: "Export")
let destinationURL = destinationFolderURL.appending(path: "Room.usdz")
do {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: destinationFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
    try finalResults?.export(to: destinationURL, exportOptions: .model)
    let newUsdz = destinationURL;
    let asset = MDLAsset(url: newUsdz);
    let obj = destinationFolderURL.appending(path: "Room.obj")
    try asset.export(to: obj)
}

Not sure what's wrong here.  According to MDLAsset documentation, .obj is a supported format and the other formats like .stl and .ply work fine and retain the original 3D shape.
Some things I've tried:

changing "exportOptions" to parametric, mesh, or model.
simply changing the filename extension of "destinationURL" (throws error)

